# Zabbix trigger for finding difference in the previous and current item output

Tags: powershell, zabbix

I have got an item, which executes some powershell script on remote machine, it returns string. I want to set zabbix trigger, to activate if current and previous output of script are different. I have tried something like this:

```
{MyTemplate:MyItem.diff()=1}
```

and also:

```
{MyItem.change(0)}#0
```

None of them seem to be working. Any ideas how to solve it?

Ok I solved this problem, turned out, that i have not connected host to template and he wasn't sending any data back.

This solution turned out to be good, but not exactly what i wanted to achieve. So now I would like to create trigger which activates if item value is not empty. Because it returns some text, I thought it would be the best to execute it if length of item is greater than 0. But I can't find this expression in documentation and I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Superuser! Can you provide more information: strings you're testing with, how exactly are you testing, what Zabbix version are you using? Where have you defined the trigger, in the same template as the item? And is the trigger attached to the host? 
The first example should be working, so if you could provide more information, that would make it easier for us. Add that information by editing your question, not commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions

the function you're looking for is `strlen (<sec|#num>,<time_shift>)`

so `{MyTemplate:MyItem.strlen()=0}` I guess